# Wrongly indicate not enough memory when installing the app

Tags: android, memory, installation

I am developing an app with Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2 and Android platform 2.2 r3.
I have set android:installLocation="preferExternal". The app also correctly installs on the SD-card on my ZTE with Android 2.2.

But...

The installation fail when the **phone** memory is less than the needs for the app I am installing.
It seams that the installation program check the phone memory instead of the SD card.
Is there any fix for this?
Can this problem appear also when the app installs from Android Market?

Hope someone is kind enough to help me on this. I am planing to release the app shortly.

Answer (score 1):

> The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user
>   data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are
>   saved on the internal device memory.

*From [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)*

Which means there are parts which won't be placed on your external storage, even if you decide to install your app there. A bit of memory is always used on the internal one. And your free memory might not be enough for that.

That is relevant for every install, so even when installing from the market.

Comment: The app storage is 34 MB. Only 0.02 MB stores in the internal memory. I now noticed that the phone indicate that the internal sorage is getting low during the upload process. So it seams to be temporary files in the phone memory.

Comment: Perhaps I have to take another approach. Most of the space is in mp3-files. Is it possible to copy this files to a directory on the SD card during the installation process instead of including them in the apk file?

Comment: Hey, oh yeah didn't think of that. Yes the files get cached on the internal memory as far as I know. Had a problem with that with my desire and cyanogenmod once. When it comes to excluding the files, what you can do is install the app and let it download all the files on the first run. That's what many game devs or apps like navigon do when they have gigabytes of stuff they need. But that involves your own hosting/server, the market doesn't support that kind of extra-distribution (yet) if I'm not mistaken ....

Comment: ... although google announced that at I/O (see [this PDF](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/android_market_for_developers.pdf), page 20) with target in June. Research a bit, maybe I just missed it since I don't need it.